# iterator operator overload ++ & -- has an argument int but not used

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading

I came across this kind of function signature at multiple sources. It has an argument `int` but function logic do not use the argument. I am not sure why this is defined in this way ? . If the argument is not need, why not just declare the function with out argument.

```
  iterator operator--(int) {
     iterator copy(*this);
     operator--();
     return copy;
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a dummy parameter just used to differentiate between the [prefix and postfix operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec).

> The int parameter is a dummy parameter used to differentiate between
>   prefix and postfix versions of the operators. When the user-defined
>   postfix operator is called, the value passed in that parameter is
>   always zero, although it may be changed by calling the operator using
>   function call notation (e.g., a.operator++(2) or operator++(a, 2)).